# Changing values in `php.ini` not taking effect in Nginx

Tags: php, nginx, alibaba-cloud-ecs, easy-engine

I am using Easyengine for a WordPress site, and I need to upload a large file to the server, I know I can use FTP / SSH to do so but in the long run I need it to be done via PHP, and the current upload limit that I see is `100M` when doing `phpinfo();`

The setup uses PHP 7 and the PHP `INI` file that I found is at

`etc/php/7.2/php.ini`

I made changes to these parts:

```
upload_max_filesize = 2100M
post_max_size = 2100M
```

But even after this the upload limit is 100M as I can see on both WordPress plugin page that I am using as well as with `phpinfo()`

I read somewhere that Nginx needs to be restarted so I did `ee site restart example.com` and both Nginx and PHP were restarted still no effect.

Some articles suggested adding a rule to `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` but unfortunately that path doesn't even exist, so I created that file at that path and tried but still no use.

Comment: Have you restarted `php-fpm` ?

Comment: Doing `ee site restart` restarted both Nginx and PHP, I didn't see anything like `php-fpm`, I saw it being mentioned on other forums but while running `php-fpm` command it didn't bring anything.

Answer (score 5):

To troubleshoot your issue, I'd take the following steps:

1. Check your `php.ini` path to check if you're editing the right one

To find your `php.ini`, create a file called `info.php` or any other name in your webroot and add the following:

```
<?php phpinfo();
```

Now, go to your browser and visit: http:///test.php. On the resulting page search for:

```
Configuration File (php.ini) Path
```

That will show you your `php.ini` location

2. Check if your PHP script isn't overwriting your settings using `ini_set()`
3. Check if your settings aren't overwritten in your `pool.d` fpm config file.

   ## In most configurations, it's located at

   /etc/php/*/fpm/pool.d/www.conf
4. Make sure you restart `php-fpm` and `nginx`.

   ## To do so

   sudo /etc/init.d/php-fpm restart
   sudo /etc/init.d/nginx restart

Comment: 1. Loaded config file's address is `/usr/local/etc/php/php.ini` but that path is not there on my directory structure, however `etc/php/7.2/php.ini` is the only `ini` file 2. No `ini_set()` in use anywhere. 3. Where is this `pool.d` file? 4. Running `php-fpm` on my SSH brings nothing.  I did restart PHP itself.

Comment: @DeepakKamat Sorry for the delayed response. I've edited my answer.

Comment: You may need to include php version to restart the php-fpm service e.g ```sudo /etc/init.d/php7.4-fpm```

Answer (score 0):

I also faced this kind of issue. I was editing wrong file located at /etc/php/8.0/cli/php.ini instead of correct one. Because nginx uses php-fpm version. So correct file was **/etc/php/8.0/fpm/php.ini**

And don't forget to kill current fpm process with sudo pkill php-fpm8.0 command. then type sudo service php8.0-fpm to start service normally.

Answer (score 0):

The correct syntax for `php.ini` is `post_max_size = 30M`, but I write `post_max_size: 30M`. And this costs me a whole day.

Also, in the `phpinfo()`, there is `Additional .ini files parsed`. I'm new to PHP but it seems that these files are overwriting `php.ini` in the order they are listed. So I create a `99-php.ini` file in the same directory, making sure it is the last one in the list.

And also don't forget to restart `php-fpm`. In my case, I am using ubuntu, so I run `sudo systemctl restart php8.1-fpm`.

Hope this can save someone's time.